# I can't use HTML select within Dojo Tooltip

Tags: firefox, drop-down-menu, tooltip, dojo

I need a Dojo tooltip with a drop-down-list. Unfortunately the tooltip closes when the cursor is moved over the drop-down-list, because the list overhangs the tooltip's div.

Is there any workaround? Could the close-automatism be disabled temporarily?

```
<div class="dojoPopupContainer dojoTooltip showComboBox"
        style="position: absolute; z-index: 1001; left: 287px; top: 15px;"
        dojoattachpoint="containerNode">
    <div id="showComboBox6e" wicket:id="showComboBox">
        <form>
            <select class="selectOneListbox" size="1">
                <option value="1">option 1</option>
                <option value="2">option 2</option>
                <option value="3">option 3</option>
            </select>
            <button value="submit" type="button" name="submit">send</button>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Update** Looks like this is a browser-specific issue. The problem occurs with Firefox (3.6), but works with Internet Explorer (8). I still need a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dijit.Tooltip is just meant to contain (rich text), you should be using dijit.TooltipDialog.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try and create the tooltip using `dijit.showTooltip()` and close it using `dijit.hideTooltip()` whenever you want to close it.